# Is it possible to inventory MSSQL-Linux running within Docker?

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker

Part of my job involves data collection to help size workloads that could be transferred to the cloud. An element of this is being able to enumerate SQL instances within a client's environment for insights such as "hey you have some out of support legacy SQL here that was supposed to be decommed years ago, what's the deal."

With the release of SQL Server 2017, I've just now created an instance of the SQL Server Enterprise 2017 on Linux container (using [this image](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/)) that I'm running locally on Windows 10. I can connect to the instance via SSMS and SELECT @@VERSION to confirm it's legit, but my question is if it is possible to inventory the device and find the SQL instance without knowing that connection string.

Things I've tried:

-Running on Windows 10 so I believe this is supported via Hyper-V, when I try to go through the Hyper-V manager to connect to the VM Docker spun up, can't get any interface there (which I figured, since Docker emulates apps rather than full VMs)

-Tried to do a sqlcmd -L from the Win10 host device and don't see the instance (Don't have SQL installed on the Windows 10 device I'm running this from)

-I can find the docker image via a docker ps, then exec -it to bash, and use sqlcmd from there, but the sqlcmd -L isn't listed as an option within Linux.

-ipconfig from the host device shows the Docker IP address, but it wouldn't give me the port information so I would have to scan through all the ports which feels dirty.

I'm kind of at a loss at this point. If I didn't explicitly know a Docker container was running MSSQL-Linux, is there any way I could identify that from inventorying the host device? (sorry for the long post)

Comment: Just so I understand this; you have a Windows 10 machine. On that Windows 10 machine, you're running a Linux VM. Then you want to interrogate the version of SQL on that VM from Windows?

Comment: @Xedni Yes, sorry for any ambiguity. I am on Windows 10 running this image: https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/, I'll update the question to add that clarity. Normally for Windows devices I would look at services or add-remove programs on the host/VM for SQL, but not sure how to go about that with the Linux container.

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head on it for a bit I've found a painful workaround of:

connect to the container's bash using: `docker exec -it <container_name> "bash"` 
then using `ps aux | grep sql` to list all of the sql processes. The MS image shows up as /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr from local testing. Once SQL has been identified you can attempt to connect to it using the Docker ip from `ipconfig` and the port from `docker ps`

It's not elegant, but it should be possible to automate those steps for use across a set of unknown devices.

Leaving this open for a bit for any better alternatives.